# How to open a video on my mobile responsive website (iPhones only) using the default player of my mobile (when clicking on a link or image)

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a mobile responsive website with an image.

```
<img src="anyImage.jpg" />
```

I want to open a video on fullscreen using the default player of the mobile (any iphone) - when clicking on the image.

Is that possible using HTML? or any other way? (I code with html, css, jQuery and php).

I tried using `<a href="video.avi">` and it sends me to a page where they ask me if I want to download the video - which is not what I want.

*Note: I don't want to embed a video! I want it to open externally using the default player.

Comment: _I code with html, css, jquery and php._ Good to know, but where's the mentioned code? We won't write you a solution.

Comment: There is no code. blank page, 3 images. when clicking on an image -> the default player of the mobile runs a video on a full screen. how do I do this using HTML? <a href=""> ?

Comment: This still doesn't validate your question for the SO purpose. We're here to help you with YOUR code, not to code it for YOU. Neither to suggest tools, libraries or similar things.

Comment: I edited my text, maybe now it's more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [this link](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html). Make sure you use a codec that iPhone supports, such as MP4 or H.264.

Use the HTML5 video tag, for example:

```
<video loop autoplay controls="true" width='100%' height='100%' src='video.mp4' type='video/mp4'></video>
```

Comment: Do I add the text/img tag in between?

Comment: Oh, It just creates the video window. So I guess i have to add a div around it.

Comment: Is there any way to make it run in an external way like the videos you click on the appstore?

Comment: I haven't found a way to do that yet. Sorry